# Determining whether a nondeterministic finite automaton accepts every possible string

Tags: math, computer-science, nfa, automaton, computer-science-theory

Given an NFA, is there a way to determine whether it accepts all strings constructed from its alphabet, without having to iterate over the infinite set of possible strings?

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Here's one algorithm:

1. Run the subset construction to turn the NFA into a DFA.
2. Minimize the DFA using a DFA minimization algorithm.
3. Check whether the DFA consists of a single state that's accepting. If so, the original NFA accepts everything. If not, there's at least one string the NFA doesn't accept.

There may be a faster algorithm than this (step (1) could take time exponential in the size of the input NFA), but this shows that there is indeed some algorithm for solving this problem.